# Fetch PHAsset with 'hidden = YES' predicate crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset

As listed in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHFetchOptions_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014396-CH1-SW2), PHAsset supports `hidden (or isHidden)` fetch key. But when I'm trying to fetch hidden assets my app crashing with following log:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate in fetch options: hidden == 1'

Here is sample code:

```
PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
options.wantsIncrementalChangeDetails = YES;
options.includeAllBurstAssets = YES;
options.includeHiddenAssets = YES;
options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hidden = YES"];

PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:options];

return fetchResult;
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not read the question carefully in my first answer, perhaps this will help

If you only want the Hidden Albums why not use ?
subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumAllHidden

```
PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
options.wantsIncrementalChangeDetails = YES;
options.includeAllBurstAssets = YES;
options.includeHiddenAssets = YES;
options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == %d",PHAssetMediaTypeImage];

PHFetchResult *albums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumAllHidden options:nil];
```

Comment: There are several ways how to fetch hidden assets, including yours one. The question is not about "how to", but "why is my valid code crashes".

Comment: OK understood, I will leave the answers up, regardless.